# How does SLURM authentication and encryption work?

Tags: slurm

I'm looking into the security of SLURM. None of the documentation is very clear about how it works. So far I have ascertained that *authentication* of users is done using [MUNGE](https://github.com/dun/munge).

As far as I can tell MUNGE works like this:

1. All machines in the cluster must have trusted `root`. In other words, untrusted users can use them, but they should not have `root` access.
2. All the machines have a `munge` user that runs `munged`, and a pre-shared `mungekey` that is **only readable by the `munge` user**.
3. All machines must use the same UIDs and GIDs for all users.

Then a user can prove that they are user `dave` (UID 7), by simply sending a `sign this payload as being from me: ...` request over a Unix socket to `munged`. `munged` apparently has a way of reliably getting the UID of the sender (I didn't look up how), so it puts the payload, `mungekey` and `uid=7` into a cryptographer, which spits out a credential.

The user can send that credential with the payload to any other node in the cluster, and since it has the same list of UIDs and the same `mungekey` it can verify that the payload did in fact come from `dave`.

Seems reasonable, but what about *encryption*? Are any of the communications between nodes encrypted at all? As far as I can tell they are not, which seems like a big oversight in this decade.